# How to. automate nutrition calculation

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, dataset

Given a vector of quantities:

```
fbs = {6.18*10^6, 2.663*10^6, 1.4735*10^7};
```

I like to create the following code:

```
kcal = WolframAlpha["6.18`*^6 tons of wheat + 2.663`*^6 tons of potato + 
       1.4735`*^7 tons of vegetables", {{"CaloriesPlus", 1}, "ComputableData"}];
```

by replacing the quantities in **fbs** in **kcal**. The question is how to insert the numbers in **fbs** into the numbers in **kcal**, which are strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) and [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html).

```
fbs = {6.18*10^6, 2.663*10^6, 1.4735*10^7};
foods = {"wheat", "potato", "vegetables"};

StringRiffle[MapThread[ToString@InputForm@#1 <> " tons of " <> #2 &, {fbs, foods}], 
  " + "]

(* 6.18*^6 tons of wheat + 2.663*^6 tons of potato + 1.4735*^7 tons of vegetables *)
```

Note that instead of using `WolframAlpha`, you can get the results directly from entities.

```
MapThread[
 #1 -> EntityInstance[Interpreter["Food"][#1], 
     Quantity[#2, "MetricTons"]][
    EntityProperty["Food", "AbsoluteTotalCaloriesContent"]] &, {foods,
   fbs}]
(* {"wheat" -> Quantity[2.1*10^13, "DietaryCalories"], 
    "potato" -> Quantity[2.4*10^12, "DietaryCalories"], 
    "vegetables" -> Quantity[8.3*10^12, "DietaryCalories"]} *)

Total@Values@%
(* Quantity[3.1*10^13, "DietaryCalories"] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

kcal = WolframAlpha[
   "6.18`*^6 tons of wheat + 2.663`*^6 tons of potato + 
       1.4735`*^7 tons of vegetables", {{"CaloriesPlus", 1}, 
    "ComputableData"}];

fbs = {6.18*10^6, 2.663*10^6, 1.4735*10^7};
```

Using [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)

```
kcal === 
 WolframAlpha @@ {StringTemplate[
     "`` tons of wheat + `` tons of potato + 
       `` tons of vegetables"] @@ fbs, {{"CaloriesPlus", 1}, 
    "ComputableData"}}

(* True *)
```